# Deny WRITE access to specific branch in gitolite

Tags: git, branch, gitolite

There is my part of my gitolite conf:

```
repo myproject
    RW+             = teamlead1 teamlead2
    -               = dev1 dev2 dev3
    R   production  = dev1 dev2 dev3
    RW+             = dev1 dev2 dev3
    R               = deploy
```

So, I want:

1. teamleads to have full control of myproject repo
2. devs to have only READ perms for "production" branch, and full access to any other branch
3. deploy user to have only READ permissions to any branch

For the moment with such conf teamleads and devs can push to production branch. I tested it with gitolite2 and gitolite3 versions with no success.

**Update0**. 
I'm really sorry, I miss "production" branch specification in DENY line.

So, I made a little modification of my gitolite.conf

```
repo myproject
    RW+             = teamlead1 teamlead2
    -  production   = dev1 dev2 dev3
    RW+             = dev1 dev2 dev3
    R               = deploy
```

So, here is the output of gitolite access check(thanks to **kostix**):

```
gitolite3@gitolite:~$ bin/gitolite access -s myproject dev1 W production
legend:
    d => skipped deny rule due to ref unknown or 'any',
    r => skipped due to refex not matching,
    p => skipped due to perm (W, +, etc) not matching,
    D => explicitly denied,
    A => explicitly allowed,
    F => denied due to fallthru (no rules matched)

  D        gitolite.conf:125        -   refs/heads/production   = dev1 dev2 dev3

W refs/heads/production myproject dev1 DENIED by refs/heads/production
```

For READ access I have:

```
  D        gitolite.conf:125        -   refs/heads/production   = dev1 dev2 dev3

R refs/heads/production myproject dev1 DENIED by refs/heads/production
```

But in practice I can clone and also push to the **production** branch from the remote server.

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 229 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To gitolite3@gitolite.myproject.com:myproject.git
   1527c05..8485ede  production -> production
```

**Update1**

1) for 
ssh -vvv gitolite3@gitolite.myproject.com info
I have

```
hello dev1, this is gitolite3@gitolite running gitolite3 v3.6.1-6-gdc8b590 on git 2.0.4

 R W    deploy
 R W    deploy_test
 R W    myproject
```

2)for

```
ssh-keygen -y
```

I've alreday made ssh keypaire with ssh-keyg-gen. By the way, situation is the same for dev2 and dev3 etc
3)I have only one string matches "dev1":

```
command="/srv/gitolite3/bin/gitolite-shell dev1",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz.....
```

Comment: Updated my answer in an attempt to analyze the new input data.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a definitive answer but I'll try to get you going into the right direction…

First of all, consider grouping your users to make rules more maintainable, like this:

```
@teamleads = teamlead1 teamlead2
@devs = dev1 dev2 dev3

repo myproject
    RW+             = @teamleads
    -               = @devs
    R   production  = @devs
    RW+             = @devs
    R               = deploy
```

The next thing to consider is *how* gitolite checks access.  This is explained [here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#when-does-gitolite-check-access) — see the picture on the right.

A few things to understand:

- Fetching (and hence cloning) is the `R` operation.
- Pushing is the `W` operation (or `W+`, if forced).
- gitolite applies rules it gathers from the config in order they appear until some of them matches.

As a corollary, `R` in a given rule does not apply to pushes and `W` in a given rule does not apply to fetches.

So let's see how gitolite goes through your rule set when a developer is pushing to the branch "production".

First, it sees this set of rules:

1. `RW+             = @teamleads`
2. `-               = @devs`
3. `R   production  = @devs`
4. `RW+             = @devs`
5. `R               = deploy`

It then discards those not applicable to the user requested the operation and ends up with:

1. `-               = @devs`
   Must have denied the operation requested (but it didn't).
2. `R   production  = @devs`
   Not considered as the operation is not `W`.
3. `RW+             = @devs`
   Should allow the push (and forced push).

As you can see, (1) must have prevented the push but it didn't.

Hence my take on this is that you have some rule earlier than this paticular entry for that project which takes precedence.

In either case, you can [peer at how gitolite processes your rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#tracing-the-access-control-decision) using the `gitolite` program itself on the server.

I typically do this using `su` to first "became" the user gitolite uses to do its work, like in

```
# su git -l -s /bin/sh
$ gitolite access -s myproject dev1 W refs/heads/production
```

I'm not sure but I suppose you'll need gitolite v3 for this to work.

---

**Update #0** following the same-numbered update to the answer.

Could you please double check that the key SSH used when authenticating at the server indeed maps to the `dev1` gitolite's user and not someone else?

Please try this:

1. Run

   ```
   ssh -vvv gitolite3@gitolite.myproject.com info
   ```

   to see what identity (key) file was used.

   This command (`info`) alone should be okay for figuring out what user gitolite thinks your SSH key *authorizes* you as: gitolite prints this in the second line of its informational output.

   The other steps are hence optional but I have included them for completeness—to may be make it more clear how gitolite maps keys to its virtual users.
2. Extract and print its public part using

   ```
   ssh-keygen -y
   ```
3. Go to the gitolite's configuration and try to find that public part in the file `.ssh/authorized_keys` there; see what user this key is mapped to.

   This file is basically a set of lines—one per gitolite's virtual user—which
   are organized like this:

   ```
   command="/usr/share/gitolite3/gitolite-shell USER",OPTS KEY_TYPE PUBKEY
   ```

   so that the SSH key of the type `KEY_TYPE` with the public part `PUBKEY` is mapped to a gitolite user `USER` and is forced to use the specified command.

Comment: Thax. I had a "little" mistake in the first post. I've just changed the it.Also I made an access check with "gitolite access" command.